# morphia query against relationship/reference

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a product document which has a reference to review array - `Review[]` Reviews.
Review has ranking 1-5.

How do I go about query against review for this product that is 4 stars ranking and above?

I tried `criteria("Reviews.ranking").Equal(4).asList()`

It complaint that it couldn't find Reviews.

Comment: Only embedded objects can be filtered using this way 
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180853/filter-list-of-embedded-documents-with-reference-field  and see also [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)