# Filter list of embedded documents with reference field

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and I'm experiencing it with mongoengine.
Given this 'User' model where 'bets' is an embedded document list which each element contains a reference to a 'match' document,

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("53df77cef4c9610f28cbff14"), 
  "name" : "Test", 
  "admin" : false, 
  "bets" : [ 
             { "match" : ObjectId("53e1511df4c9610bf52f5b7a"), "expectedResult" : "1" } 
           ] 
 }
```

how can I get 'bets' elements, passed to query the matchId?

I tried to do

```
User.objects.filter(bets__match={'match._id':match.id})
```

where 'match' is the object I need to filter by but I get an empty array.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use Mongo as a relational database... This is not really how mongo was designed to be used. Am I correct? Are you trying to execute sub-queries?

Comment: I know it sounds like a relational approach. But how can I simply apply changes to a Match object to all documents whose relate to that object? So, I use a ReferenceField in bets list. Can I design the schema differently?

Comment: This may help you http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#array-match-embedded-documents

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index

Comment: Read. But can I make queries on a referenced document in embedded document? That's what I'd need. At least I change the model logic.